# How to show data before 27 days from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am adding some data with start date and end date in `MySQL`. If suppose i have one row in mysql table with `end_date` is `07/03/2018`. Now i want to give notification to user that his `end_date` is coming on his dashboard. I want to show notification from `10/02/2018` till `end_date`. It means from `10/02/2018` this date to `07/03/2018` user will see notification daily on his dashboard. How to write query for this. Below is my normal query to show all data from table but I don't know how to add above condition in this scenario.

```
$Records =  "
     SELECT *, 
      DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS start_date,
      DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS end_date,ORG_NAME 
     FROM vat_report 
     LEFT JOIN organizations ON vat_report.org_id = organizations.org_id";
$exec = $database_resultsObj -> execQuery ( $Records );
```

Comment: You need to add a WHERE statement

Comment: but what to add in where statement give some hint

Comment: the date span :D How is your date-format in the database? Y-m-d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the mysql-functions `CURDATE()` and `DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 27 DAY)`. In your case that would look something like this:

```
SELECT     *, 
           DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS start_date,
           DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS end_date,
           ORG_NAME 
FROM       vat_report 
LEFT JOIN  organizations 
ON         vat_report.org_id = organizations.org_id 
WHERE      CURDATE() >= DATE_SUB(end_date, INTERVAL 27 DAY)
AND        CURDATE() <= end_date
```